Making interactable QgsRangeSlider with PyQGIS
In QGIS 3.36 using PyQGIS I would like to make a window with inside a range slider. I was able to show to user a window and, inside a slider, but this is not interactable: it's like an image. How can I make this interactable?
Here is the code:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from qgis.gui import QgsRangeSlider

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(796, 600)
        self.slider = QgsRangeSlider(MainWindow)
        self.slider.resize(650, 200)
        self.slider.setGeometry(120,260,570,50)
        self.slider.setMinimum(1000)
        self.slider.setMaximum(2020)
        self.slider.setSingleStep(10)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 420, 71, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 420, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setEnabled(True)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(4, 105, 791, 21))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 4))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Scelta range temporale"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ok"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Annulla"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Scegli una data d'inizio e fine ricerca"))


        
if __name__ == "__console__":
    
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

This is a conversion from a '.ui' file created with QtDesigner.
Here the image of a window with the slider


Do i understand it correctly that you execute your code in the QGIS Python console? I pasted your code into QGIS Python Console and it seems to work.  I used QGIS 3.34.10 and QGIS 3.28.16. Maybe its a version problem?

I use QGIS 3.36, yes I execute the code in the QGIS Python console.

Are you saying that you can't move the slider with the mouse??

Exactly. It is like a fixed image.

Could you add a screen cast to your question showing this issue? Because I can't reproduce this behavior. Other than the fact that your slider is larger than the window and sits at the very bottom of it because apparently you don't use Qt layouts, the slider is movable when I run this code. Tested in 3.28, 3.34 & a recent build of master branch from GitHub.

I understood the problem. I posted a code without some rows because I thought they weren't important, instead the result is different.

I updated the Question. Excuse me.

The simplest fix here is to make self.slider a child widget of the central widget like the other widgets are. Of course you will need to declare self.slider after self.centralwidget. Also, please look into some layout tutorials e.g. PyQt Layouts and PyQt5 Layouts. Arranging widgets by manipulating their geometries is not the way to go since it doesn't work consistently across different sized screens and devices. Also note that when you resize your main window, the widgets do not move or resize to accommodate and will disappear out of view if you reduce the window size too much. Layouts solve this problem.
Below is a simple example based on the code in your question, modified to solve your main issue and using layouts to manage the widgets. I have also added a couple of spin boxes which are synced with the slider via the QgsRangeSlider.rangeChanged and QSpinBox.valueChanged signals. This is useful both for fine scale adjustment and to see the slider values while dragging.
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from qgis.gui import QgsRangeSlider

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.main_window = MainWindow
        self.main_window.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.main_window.resize(800, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.main_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setFixedHeight(25)
        self.label.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.slider = QgsRangeSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.slider.setMinimum(1000)
        self.slider.setMaximum(2020)
        #self.slider.setSingleStep(10)
        self.slider.setTickInterval(100)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)

        self.min_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('Min:', self.centralwidget)
        self.min_val = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.min_val.adjustSize()
        self.min_val.setRange(self.slider.minimum(), self.slider.maximum())
        self.min_val.valueChanged.connect(self.values_changed)
        self.max_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('Max:', self.centralwidget)
        self.max_val = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.max_val.adjustSize()
        self.max_val.setRange(self.slider.minimum(), self.slider.maximum())
        self.max_val.valueChanged.connect(self.values_changed)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.main_window.close())

        self.main_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        # Use Qt layouts to arrange widgets
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_layout.addWidget(self.min_lbl)
        self.lbl_layout.addWidget(self.min_val)
        self.lbl_layout.addStretch()
        self.lbl_layout.addWidget(self.max_lbl)
        self.lbl_layout.addWidget(self.max_val)
        self.btn_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_layout.addStretch()
        self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.main_layout.addStretch()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.slider)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.lbl_layout)
        self.main_layout.addStretch()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.btn_layout)

        self.slider.rangeChanged.connect(self.slider_changed)
        
        self.retranslateUi(self.main_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Scelta range temporale"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ok"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Annulla"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Scegli una data d'inizio e fine ricerca"))
        
    def slider_changed(self, min, max):
        self.min_val.setValue(min)
        self.max_val.setValue(max)
        
    def values_changed(self):
        self.slider.setRange(self.min_val.value(), self.max_val.value())
        
    def do_something(self):
        min = self.slider.lowerValue()
        max = self.slider.upperValue()
        #do something with min & max...
        
        
if __name__ == "__console__":
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

Result:

